# Sending decimals to arduino using simulink

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink, arduino-ide

As part of a project, I'm running a Hardware-In the-Loop (HIL) test using simulink and arduino. To give a brief overview, I'm building a satellite and using reaction wheels as my actuator. The physical satellite model is modelled in Simulink and my arduino controls how fast the wheel spins.

I'm trying to send data to my arduino uno using the following simulink setup:

[Simulink Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSymk.jpg)

and the following is my arduino code to receive and send the data back to simulink:

```
float x;

void setup() 
{

  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() 
{

if(Serial.available()>0){
  x = Serial.read();
 }

Serial.write((byte*)&x, sizeof(x));
Serial.print(x);
delay(1000);

}
```

I've noticed that I am only to send intergers as uint8 variables, which limits my numbers to be as big as 256. Also, whenever I try to send a decimal, what I get back on matlab is rubbish.

Is there a workaround for this? Or am I doing something wrong in my arduino code.

Thanks!

Comment: `Serial.read()` returns a single char (byte) not a float.

Comment: Looking in your simulink block diagram you perform a cast to uint8 which will round out the decimal as well as the serial read and write only send uchar or uint8. If you want to send decimal numbers I would look into how single and double precision numbers are stored. However, the simplest way to send a simple decimal number is with 2 bytes: 1 for the whole part and 1 for the fraction part and have the Arduino parse it back into a decimal number.